# Trying to upload JSON structure to Firebase web

Tags: json, firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am trying to build this structure in web Firebase (JS).
The main collection should be the id of the user, then the document should be the desired collection name and then each header of the table I need to list an array of the values of it.
So basically each element in the array, for example in the sales field in the picture below is a cell in the table and names is the next column.
Name : Morad.
Sales 300.

i have everything as a JSON. in this format :

```js
fileJson = [
{
Name: 'Morad',
Sales: 300
},
{
Name: 'James',
Sales: 600
},
]



      fileJson && Object.keys(fileJson).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = fileJson[key];
    console.log(nestedContent);


        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {

          db.collection(userId)
                .doc(tableName)
                .set({[docTitle]: nestedContent[docTitle] ? nestedContent[docTitle] : "" })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log("Document successfully written!");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                });
        });


  })
```

Comment: Could you please share what you have done until now? What have you implemented?

Comment: Sure, added it to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. But could you explain what error are you getting or where are you getting stuck? I found a very useful [Tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/firebase-import-json-to-firestore-ed6a4adc2b57) to import Json to Firebase Firestore. Please have look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, I'll go over it. The code is working but its overwriting everything, so its uploading the json content but the values are over written and just the last field is bieng stored

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding regarding how promises work.

You have **db.collection.set(...)** which is a promise inside a forEach loop, this is causing the promises not having enough time to be resolved and saved.

In other words, you have a foreach loop where you want to store the data into the Firestore and with **.then()** you are resolving the promise that the element was stored correctly. But we have to wait for .then() function to be resolved first rather than going to the next element. We can do this by saving all the promises into an array and then resolve all the promises.

You can use the following code:

```
function yourFunction() {

    // Your previous code, in case you have

    fileJson = [
    {
        Name: 'Morad',
        Sales: 300
    },
    {
        Name: 'James',
        Sales: 600
    },
    ]

    let promises = [];

    fileJson && Object.keys(fileJson).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = fileJson[key];
    console.log(nestedContent);

        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {

          let promise = db.collection(userId)
                .doc(tableName)
                .set({[docTitle]: nestedContent[docTitle] ? nestedContent[docTitle] : "" });

          promises.push(promise);
        });

        // Alternative using map function instead
        //
        // let promises =  Object.keys(nestedContent).map(docTitle => {
        //     return db.collection(userId)
        //         .doc(tableName)
        //         .set({[docTitle]: nestedContent[docTitle] ? nestedContent[docTitle] : "" });
        // });

    })

    Promise.all(promises).then(value => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });

    // Your following code, in case you have
}
```

You can take a look to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to understand how many promises can be waited until they have been resolved using an iterable such as an array.

Comment: Thanks Nibrass!
Tried your code, still gave me the same result. it overwrites the content and leaves just the last cell. 
I figured it out, so ill add the answer in a separate answer to hopefully help devs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Firestore (converted to Firestore)** query that was used, when the object was in the right format Firebase accepted it.

```
     const data = arrToObject(fileJson);
     const docRef = db.collection(userId).doc(tableName);
     await docRef.set({ data });


  fileJson=[];
```

Receiving an array in my request so converting it to object with this function:

```
function arrToObject(arr) {
  // flattening(arr);
  //assuming header
  var keys = arr[0];
  //vacate keys from main array
  var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);

  var formatted = [],
    data = newArr,
    cols = keys,
    l = cols.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d = data[i],
      o = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) o[cols[j]] = d[j] ? d[j] : "";
    formatted.push(o);
  }
  return formatted;
}
```